Earliest time to fulfill Krias Shema at night
What are some opinions brought down in Halacha for the minimum number of minutes after sunset that one can fulfill their obligation to say Shema at night?

Why the down vote?

Note any such opinion would be from the last 200 years or so when urban Jews forgot how to look at the sky and tried to reverse engineer some calculations to compensate. Every prior authority just says to look up (which would result in stars being seen when the sun is about 5-7 degrees below the horizon)

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9015/davening-maariv-at-shekiya-or-after-plag-hamincha-repeating-kriyas-shema

Also note that any such number of minutes would only be good on one date at one latitude, and you'd need a computer (or some very clever trigonometers) to extrapolate correctly to other places and times (part of why no one ever did this)

Theoretically it's the same question as "how many minutes after sunset does shabbos end?" But many are stricter on the latter as it could involve violating a capital thou-shalt-not, vs. failing to perform a thou-shalt.
It would make a lot of sense for it to depend on one's latitude -- it gets darker faster when you're close to the equator. And to measure it in degrees depression, rather than minutes. But it was usually easier to just pick a simple number of minutes.
For New York City, the typical answers you will hear about ending shabbos are 42/45/50/60/72 minutes. Some shuls will attempt to delay maariv so they will get to Shema at 20 minutes after sunset, as that's at least some serious post-sunset time ... but as best I know, the minimum to not have to repeat later is 42 (for New York).

This is incorrect. Ending Shabbat is theoretically more strict than shema and requires 3 small adjacent stars.

@DoubleAA thank you, whereas shema requires what?

In Shaarei halakha book, it says 3 average stars (not adjacent) for Shema.

Shalom Any three small stars https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31256/when-is-the-latest-time-you-can-daven-minchah-bedieved#comment159239_31256 . @YDJ 3 average stars is unquestionably the actual time for all of it, but for deorayta (like shema) we have you wait for small stars (and for shabbat adjacent stars).

@DoubleAA ah thank you. Lemaysa, for those who don't know stars from anything, are there poskim today who won't tell people to repeat shema if said <42 in NYC?

Surely. There are reasonable poskim who don't require repeating after the sun is ~6.5-7° below the horizon, which is about 33-36 minutes after astronomical sunset today in nyc. See Pninei Halacha for instance. RHSchacter also has a similar position I understand that they use for timing minyanim at yu

@DoubleAA is RHS saying "if we time maariv that way, we'll probably have been yotzei and davened b'tzibur, but we advise saying it again later", or "if you say it at 36, you don't have to say it again later"?

@Shalom I don't speak for him, but id bet he'd tell anyone it's good to repeat after Rabbenu Tam but that the minyan time assumes regular people won't repeat and that's not worth any big fuss.

Note also for derabanan issues you could even go ~5+ minutes earlier for medium stars (eg. fast days, bedikat chametz, starting seder, counting omer, Chanukah candles, etc.)

@DoubleAA right, though these days, for a lot of folks it would be scandalous to hear that someone ends 17 Tammuz at <42.

@Shalom nah, everyone in ny has seen myzmanim prints earlier times, usually labeled as r tucacinsky as if he's the only one https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44206/759
